# explaining LARS algorithm in a simple way

Tags: self-study, lars

I am thinking to write a LARS algorithm that uses different optimizations in each step. Can somebody briefly explain Least angel regression, LARS ([see here](http://statweb.stanford)) to me? then I will try to write my own LARS in R. Or if you have a simple R code (that shows just core of the function and not lots of details) I will appreciate to have a look at that.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala Usually, but not always; the [help/on-topc](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) states: "*If the language is statistically oriented (such as R, SAS, Stata, SPSS, etc.), then decide based on the nature of your question: if it needs statistical expertise to understand or answer, ask it here*..." means it's *sometimes* okay that a question involve code. Indeed, `r` is our biggest tag by some distance ... and many of those answers and question do contain R code (though generally in the context of a statistical issue).

Comment: Actually it doesn't have an answer...